# Maven Profile with Archetype

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

I am trying to generate custom maven archetype and based on certain parameters I want to choose a particular maven profile.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=${archetype_groupId} -DarchetypeArtifactId=${archetype_artifactId} -DarchetypeVersion=1.0.0 -DgroupId=${groupId} -DartifactId=${artifactId} -Dversion=${version} -Dpackage=${packageName} -DgatewayName=${gatewayName} -P profile-1
```

The profile with id(profile-1) is created in the pom.xml:

```
<profiles>
<profile>
    <id>profile-1</id>
    <activation>
        <!-- <property>
            <name>test.property</name>
            <value>rest</value>
        </property> -->
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
    </activation>
    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/archetype-resources/src/main/resources</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>_fileName_Handler.xml</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
</profile>
```

When the above mvn archetype:generate is executed, I get the exception:

```
The requested profile "profile-1" could not be activated because it does not exist.
```

Can anyone please help ?

Comment: the profile configuration into pom looks fine: are you sure you are launching the command from the right path? Can you check that is reading the right pom.xml ? Looks like he's reading another pom (where there's no profile-1)

Comment: what do you have it in `<activatedProfile>` in your `.m2/settings.xml` ?